# installation lxml package Python

Tags: python, package, lxml

I cant install lxml package for python scraping. I installed required lbraries C  http://users.skynet.be/sbi/libxml-python/ . Tryed it with python 2.7 2.7 3.4 .  dowsnt work still cant install my lxml package .

Comment: How are you installing ?? Try package manager pip

Answer (score 0):

Use the required .whl file from any source [Example](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml) and use pip.

`pip install "location where .whl is saved"`

Pip can be found in `PYTHONHOME/Scripts`. pip is available by default from 2.7.10

Comment: You are genius . I know what is pip baby =)

Comment: @Jack accept the answer if it worked. make a habit of upvoting and downvoting an answer.